# Image size issue in nexus 5 and samsung s8

Tags: android, screen

[image][image]I am having an issue with image size in particular with samsung s8 and emulator nexus5

Basically with the last 4 images(attached),As there is quite a space is samsung s8,I have created seprate dimens file to target different screen size.
So I created values-hdpi ,values-xdpi,values-xxdpi and values-xxxhdpi
and put dimens.xml file..
So for values-hdpi,my dimens file is

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="image_size">80dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

So for values-xxdpi,my dimens file is

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="image_size">120dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

For values-xxhdpi,

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="image_size">140dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Problem is with screen sizes 1080* 2076 and 1080 1776
With 1080*2076(samsung s8) it works fine.But with  1080*1776 (emulator nexus 5) image goes out of the screen.As they both fall in xxhdpi catgeory.Though the height of samsung s8 is larger than nexus 5.
Attached is the screen shot of the ui of samsung s8 and nexus 5

Comment: Please attach screen shot

Comment: attached! please check,attached screen shot is of nexus 5

Comment: Can please attach screen shot od Samsung s8 also

Comment: added! Please check

Comment: I have even added a separate layout for samsung s8 screen size height (360*740dp),layout-h740dp and for nexus screen height layout-h640dp.Assigning smaller height value to nexus..But it didnt work for both.They seem to be taking default height values.